# Cordova admob pro still showing test ad

Tags: cordova, admob, phonegap

I am using this code for my cordova app. I have removed the testing lines but it still showing test ad.

My app is already on play store but not showing real ad

Please help

```js
var admobid = {};

// TODO: replace the following ad units with your own
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  admobid = { // for Android
    banner: 'ca-app-pub-7394955318871729/8888928576697',
    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-7394955318871729/3765446454
  };
}

function initApp() {
  if (! AdMob ) { alert( 'admob plugin not ready' ); return; }

  // this will create a banner on startup
  AdMob.createBanner( {
    adId: admobid.banner,
    position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    overlap: false,
    offsetTopBar: false,
    bgColor: 'black'
  } );

  // this will load a full screen ad on startup
  AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    adId: admobid.interstitial,
    autoShow: true
  });
}

if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
} else {
    initApp();
}
```

Hi,
I am using this code for my cordova app. I have removed the testing lines but it still showing test ad.

My app is already on play store but not showing real ad

Please help

Comment: I tried to edit your post but the que is full. You may want to remove your unique ad IDs from you code if these are yours and not examples.